# What is the differance between a "class hierarchy diagram" and a "Class diagram"?

Tags: uml, diagram

So for my coursework we need to make a simple ordering system application, nothing hard and the code is all finished and works,

But it also requires me to make a " UML use case diagram, UML class hierarchy diagram, one class and one instance diagrams."

So for the use case diagram, easy.
For the class hierarchy diagram, done
for the instance diagram, although short, it's done,

But for the "Class diagram" i can't seem to do, what is the difference between that and the class hierarchy diagram ?

i've looked it up and the the same can someone tell me the difference ?

Many thanks

Comment: Ask your teacher. "UML Class hierarchy diagram" is not a standard UML term.

Comment: my thoughts exactly, i will thanks for your help !

Comment: Any luck with this, i'm having the same issue

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question ? I'm also interested in the response :)